# Unix Shell Scripting and Java Jar Command

Tags: shell, unix

I have a Unix shell script (bash) that sources some environment variables and then gives the user a few options.  Based on the user input I call some other Unix shell scripts that perform certain actions.  I'm having an issue with the start app server option below. When I  execute the appserver/run.sh script from main.sh I get a "Unable to access jarfile start.jar".  When I navigate directly to the run.sh script and run it from its directory, it works.  start.jar starts up a Jetty application server.  Any ideas on how to execute run.sh from main.sh?

**permissions:**

```
-rw-r--r--  1 colgray eng  42364 Jan 10 15:40 start.jar
```

**main.sh:**

```
source ./setupenvironment.sh
echo "Which Example would you like to run?"
select yn in "one" "two" "start app server" "Quit" do
    case $yn in
        "one" ) ./examples/one/scripts/one.sh; break;;
        "two" ) ./examples/twp/scripts/two.sh; break;;
        **"start app server" ) ./examples/appserver/run.sh; break;;**
         Quit ) exit;;
    esac
done
```

**/examples/appserver/run.sh:**

```
java -jar start.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running from a directory other than `./examples/appserver`, it cannot *find* your `jar` file:

```
<somewhere>                        <-- this is where you are
     |                                  ^
     +--> examples                      | <- this is a distance too far :-)
             |                          v
             +--> appserver        <- this is where start.jar is
```

Based on the fact that you seem to be running it from the directory where `examples` lives (otherwise the relative paths wouldn't work), you'll need either

```
java -jar examples/appserver/start.jar
```

or:

```
cd examples/appserver
java -jar start.jar
```

in your `run.sh` file.

Comment: changing to the directory and then running the java -jar start.jar worked, much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change run.sh to use an absolute path to start.jar.